# AngularJS implementation

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress

I just tried to implement angularjs in Wordpress.

I added script in header.php

```
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

adedd the above code in other Js file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName= "John";
    $scope.lastName= "Doe";
});
```

and I tried to print the scope value in page.php file fro following div

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{firstName}}+{{lastName}}
</div>
```

But in this case it will not showing in scope value in this page.Any one please help.

Comment: Did you use console tool to test angular object exist?

Comment: Have you added the "other JS" file as script in the header.php as well?

Comment: yes i added js file.I am not getting any error in console

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstName = "John";
  $scope.lastName = "Doe";

  $scope.fullName = function() {
    return $scope.firstName + ' ' + $scope.lastName;
  };

  $scope.counter = -1;

  $scope.$watch($scope.fullName, function() {
    $scope.counter++;
  });
});

    <html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    First name: <input ng-model="firstName" /><br>
    Last name: <input ng-model="lastName" /><br>
    Full name: {{fullName()}}<br>
    Number of times changed: {{counter}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Ref:http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/02/computer-properties-with-javascript-properties/

Comment: Still I am not getting the scope value,,

Comment: No error in my console its just printing the name like this {{name}}. the scope value is not getting..

Comment: check it and let me know

Comment: I tried with your answer.Its not working on my end.And also i debugged using chrome console.And i just put one break point inside the controller.It is not hitting on break point.That means its not executing the controller scope.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83093/discussion-between-user3541485-and-deena).

Answer (score 0):

When I compiling your code, you specified that you store the angular library file in specific location eg- c:\yourproject\angular.min.js.
So your code is correct but if you stored the angular library file in specific location then you must assure that you will use correct or exact source of angular library file(angular.min.js).The below is the reference for you.

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

I think only that is your mistake which is most of programmer forget that point.

Otherwise, check the below code which is similar scenario with your scenario.Hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried your example code this also not working on my end

Comment: Please clean your browser cookies and again try this code because it gives expected output in my browser.

Comment: step by step process might be it will help you. 
1st Step: Create a new folder namely angularJsPractice. 
2st Step: Just open notepad and copy the suggested code and past it in notepad and save in created folder location(C:\angularJsPractice).
3rd Step:Just visit the below link for angular library file.
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js
4th Step:Copy that library code and paste it a new file namely angular.min.js which is saved in same location C:\angularJSPractice\
5th Step:please add this code <script src= "angular.min.js"></script> in your page.

Comment: I am trying the HTML with .php file.It's have any problem?.Its working perfectly in html file but not in php file

Comment: have you added the below code in <Script> tag.
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.username = 'World';

  $scope.sayHello = function() {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hello ' + $scope.username + '!';
  };
}]);